# 503 upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. when multiple pods are up

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

I am using Kubernetes to deploy 5 services in multiple pods in the same namespace.

For each service I'm utilizing projectContour HTTPProxy as an Ingress. Everything works as expected if 1 or 2 services are up, however when we bring up more, the services intermittently show "503 upstream connect error" every other request?

I've been investigating if maybe this is related to lack or resources from the K8 side, but it doesn't seem like it

Service logs do not show any errors.

Comment: 503 mean ingress sending requst and backend service is down or there is issue in upstream. You should check the ingress logs also and status of pods.

Comment: @chidog12, any updates? Can you include the logs mentioned by HarshManvar?